# Deja dup backup permission issue

Tags: permissions, backup, deja-dup

After solving this issue here:
[Restore backup using Deja Dup failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045573/restore-backup-using-deja-dup-failed)

I get now always this issue when try to make new backup:

Permission denied when trying to read ‘/duplicity-inc.20180611T065903Z.to.20180611T070215Z.manifest.gpg’.

I would like now fix this somehow, or also reset all backup, delete them, and restart from scratch.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I found was to delete old backup files. Then worked fine.